# Three heaters on single PCB

Tags: temperature

(This is a follow-up to the previous [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/199140/pcb-heater-design-issues) I posted.) I'm basically trying to control three different tempeartures on a single PCB. It looks like the following:
[image: PCB Heater]

The middle pattern heats up to about 75 deg. Celsius, while the far-right and far-left ones heats up to 95 deg. Celsius. The ones between them are supposed to be controlled to 55 deg. Celsius.

This is where I'm facing problems. I think, because of the relatively high temperatures of the surrounding areas, I'm not able to control the 55 deg. heater, and the temperature keeps rising. (I'm using thermocouples to measure the temperature)

As a solution, I thought of removing the area between the heaters, so that the heat gets dissipated into the air. However, I'm not entirely sure of that theory, and needed some opinions about that. Also, the design cannot be changed at this point, so the spacing between them is pretty much a constant.